# homebrew -- Image Magick throwing version error when executing Php

Tags: php, homebrew, warnings, imagick

PHP execution is throwing a Warning about Imagick...

Output of php -v:

```
PHP Warning: Version warning: Imagick was compiled against Image Magick 
version #### but version #### is loaded. Imagick will run but may behave
surprisingly in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Does it literally have "####" as the version numbers?

Comment: Nope. but the example in the answer below was different numbers than the issue I had, so I thought it would make more sense to post as ####

Comment: BTW I raised this as an issue previously for Brew - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3919 Imagick always needs to be compiled against the version of ImageMagick installed. However nothing seems to have been implemented to enforce this.

Answer (score 14):

You have certainly upgraded imagick after installing PHP, so you need to reinstall imagick using pecl.

Run the following:

```
sudo pecl uninstall imagick
sudo pecl install imagick
```

If you run php -v and see a warning saying that the module imagick was already loaded, check your ini file:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

Then open the file and remove duplicate entries of extension="imagick.so". You might need to look into the configuration path to check also other ini files.

Comment: the question is for homebrew. not pecl.

Comment: @Artistan This is the top google result when searching for the imagick error. It's pretty unusual to install PHP extensions using homebrew so this is likely to be the correct fix for most people landing on this page.

Comment: Confirmed that this worked for me with PHP 8.1 installed through brew @ Artistan

Answer (score 2):

**php##-imagick needs to be rebottled**

```
brew reinstall --build-bottle php56-imagick
```

OR

```
brew reinstall --build-bottle php71-imagick
```

make sure you use the **reinstall** command and the proper **php##** version

[Reference to solution on github.com](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3166)

> UPD:
> '--build-bottle' is deprecated so please use 'pecl'

Comment: people keep downloading without trying. figure out which version of php you have installed and try php## as stated above..... :shrug:

Comment: --build-bottle not supported with (newer?) brews. I really hate pecl as everything feels so legacy but used it to install as described above and this works well. But pecl edits your php.ini by putting the imagick.so right on the first line of the php.ini  :sigh:

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can make the correction by creating a file called **".user.ini"** in the root directory of the domain or sub-domain in question and placing the following line inside it:

```
imagick.skip_version_check = true
```

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is:**

Create a file called **.user.ini**

Type the following into the file.

```
 imagick.skip_version_check=true
```

Save the file in the top-level folder for the site.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar PHP Warning. This is due to a mismatch between the version of ImageMagick installed and the version that Imagick compiles with.

To fix it, uninstall ImageMagick from your programs then check the ImageMagick version that Imagick compiles with in the **Imagick** section of **phpinfo()**, line **Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version**. Download and install that version. That's it!

You can find the different versions of ImageMagick here https://www.npackd.org/p/imagemagick64

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).